# Laravel 8: Mantener el sistema de rutas de laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

El sistema de rutas de laravel para la versión 8 cambió la forma en como trabaja el `ServiceProvider`. Anteriormente la el atributo `$namespace` estaba declarado de esta forma:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Sin embargo en la versión 8 el atributo viene declarado como null.

```
protected $namespace = null;
```

Por lo que las rutas en la versión 8 deben declararse de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
//Se debe llamar al controllador
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

//De esta manera puede ser usado al momento de declarar la ruta.
Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Si estas trabajando un proyecto nuevo quizás no veas mayor problema en adaptarte a la versión 8 pero si quieres migrar un sistema en el que tienes cientos o miles de rutas, quizás cambiar todas las rutas de una por una no sea una solución viable.

**¿Puedo mantenerme en el sistema de rutas anterior estando en la versión 8 de Laravel?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### La respuesta es sí:

Para ello en la documentación puedes conseguir la siguiente información:

> If you prefer Laravel 7.x style controller route prefixing, you may
> simply add the $namespace property into your application's
> RouteServiceProvider.

Básicamente tienes que hacer dos cambios en el archivo `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`:

**1. Declarar el atributo namespace de esta forma (que no es mas que mantenerlo como estaba en la versión 7.x):**

```
   protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`
```

**2. En el método boot debes pasarle el atributo declarado al método `namespace` anidado al `middleware('web')` y al `middleweare('api')`:**

```html
<?php

 public function boot()
 {
     $this->configureRateLimiting();

     $this->routes(function () {
     
         Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

         Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
     });
 }
```

De esta manera ya puedes seguir cargando tus rutas al igual que en la versión 7.x

**Fuente:**

- [Buscar Routing Namespace Update](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases)